# php query no result

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
    <?php include 'db.php';

    $GLOBALS["conn"] = conncet();

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $ime = $_POST['ime'];
        $rm = $_POST['rm'];
        $minpl = $_POST['minpl'];
        $maxpl = $_POST['maxpl'];

        $query = "select * from zaposleni where ime = '{$ime}' and radno_mesto = '{$rm}' and plata between '{$minpl}' and '{$minpl}'";
        $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["conn"], $query);

        if (!$result) {
            echo "Query failed" . mysqli_error($GLOBALS["conn"]);
        }

        $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

            if ($count == 0) {
                echo "NO RESULT";
            } else { 

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $i = $row['ime'];
            $r = $row['radno_mesto'];
            $p = $row['plata'];

                ?>

                <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Ime:</th>
                <th>Radno mesto:</th>
                <th>Plata:</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $r; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $p; ?></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>


                <?php
            } }
        if ($ime == "" || $rm = "" || $minpl = "" || $maxpl = "") {
            echo "Morate uneti sva polja";
        }

            }


    ?> 


    <form action="" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ime">Ime:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ime">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="rm">Radno mesto:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rm">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="minpl">MIN Plata:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="minpl">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="maxpl">MAX Plata:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="maxpl">
        </div>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Pretraga">
    </form>
```

it says no result, despite full database. Why is it not working? Any suggestions for this problem? It has no syntax errors. Maybe query?

https://files.fm/u/dgamw5uu#/view/Stack.PNG this is the link of database.

P.S. Name of a function conncet() is not a error, just a misspelling in a function name.

ime means name,
radno_mesto means work place
min plata means minimal salary
max plata means maximal salary

Comment: Output the query and execute on the DB, do you get results? You are open to SQL injections. `between '{$minpl}' and '{$minpl}'` seems like a typo. Should be `$maxpl`, no?

Comment: Please see about parametrised queries

Comment: Yes, it should. Thanks, can't believe that i spent whole day looking for "mistake" and it was just i typo...

Answer (score 0):

I would try this as syntax for your query : (you used minpl twice)

```
 $query = "select * from zaposleni where ime = '".$ime."' and radno_mesto = '".$rm."' and plata between ".$minpl." and ".$maxpl ;
```

and make the correct value are posted for $ime, $rm, $minpl adn $maxpl